# Can't a PHP file be stored in .html extension? I've heard that .php is not supported by some browsers i'm not sure What might be the remedy for this?

Tags: php, html

This is my sample Hello World program. Which din't work with .html extension but it is working with the . php extension.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
      <title>Untitled Document</title>
   </head>

   <body>
       <div>
          <?php echo 'Hello World!!' ?>
       </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Is it possible to save this file with .html extension? and is it true that some of the browsers doesn't support .php files?

Comment: _browsers doesn't support .php files_ o.O Servers do support php. But some servers cannot recognize php inside .html extensions

Answer (score 10, accepted):

PHP is server side languages it has nothing with browser image below  explain how php works

[image]

[Image source and good read](http://www.html.net/tutorials/php/lesson1.php)

Normally use just **`.php`** extension

Comment: Thank you i understood more with This.

Comment: Ummm, it's easy to tell a web server to parse `.extension` with PHP, which I think is what the OP was after here. E.g., I can easily tell Apache to parse `.foo` with PHP, or `.html`, etc, etc.

Comment: @TimPost what op is asking is  **is it true that some of the browsers doesn't support .php files** so i am telling above ..  i know your point is true very true .. if in case you think i improve my answer .. just let me know ill do it sir .

Answer (score 4):

There is no such thing as a browser that doesn't support PHP files. PHP is server-side.

Yes, it's possible to save that with an `.html` extension, but it might not do something meaningful, depending on your server configuration. What's wrong with using `.php`? It's  standard.

Answer (score 0):

Suhas, When you are using PHP in you code then for It must be in PHP unless you use smarty.PHP is platform independent sever side language. It do not depends on browser. use Smarty if you want to use .html extention.

Comment: Smarty is not the only templating system in the world, and besides that, the extension doesn't matter in Smarty. Likewise, PHP can be passed a file of any type (or even a non-file of any type), but the server (if one exists) may or may not be configured to associate the `.html` extension with PHP.

Comment: @minitech I know there are many things. But I am just suggesting him. not forcing anyone. By the way thank you for your comment.

Answer (score -1):

PHP is not browser based, it is a server language... there is no web browser that supports PHP.

Also if you to have PHP in your file make sure the format is PHP (its best this way).

If you are interested in PHP here is the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/index.php)